# If $u$ and $\partial_n u$ along a curve are known, then the full gradient $\nabla u$ is also known

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I just stumbled above this statement. If a curve $\Gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is given. Then if $u$ and $\partial_n u$ on $\Gamma$ are known. Then the full gradient $\nabla u$ is also known. So far, I don't see how to use the normal derivative. Any hints on that?

Comment: You also know the tangential derivative of $u$ along $\Gamma$. [$\Gamma$ needs to be nice enough for the normal derivative to be well-defined, then you can also get the tangential derivative.]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Regularity is not an issue for me. If I have the tangential derivative, is the idea then simply that $\nabla u= \partial_n u n + \partial_t u t$ where $n$ and $t$ are the normal and tangential vectors? Since I know $u$ on $\Gamma$ I can compute the tangential derivative, right?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Thank you. Would you post your comment as an answer? Then I could "close" the question.

Comment: Okay, doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As established in the comments, since $\Gamma$ needs to be sufficiently regular for the normal derivative to be defined and we know the values of $u$ on $\Gamma$, we can also take the tangential derivative along $\Gamma$. Thus, with unit normal vector $n$ and unit tangent vector $t$, we obtain

$$\nabla f = \partial_n u \cdot n + \partial_t u \cdot t$$

on $\Gamma$.